# Java passing values from run

Tags: java

In my below program, How can I access str value of SyncPipe in my doGet() class???

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

String[] command =
    {
  "zsh"
      };
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println("source ./taxenv/bin/activate");
            stdin.println("python runner.py");
            stdin.close();
            int returnCode = 0;
            try {
                returnCode = p.waitFor();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);

}               
class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
    String str="";
public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm_ = istrm;
      ostrm_ = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try
      {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
          {
             // ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
              str = str + IOUtils.toString(istrm_, "UTF-8");
              //((PrintStream) ostrm_).println();
          }
          System.out.println(str);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Finally,

all I wish to do is to pass the str value from run() into my doget(), how do I do this?

Comment: run() is a method, the str value belongs to an instance of SyncPipe. If you have reference to an instance of SyncPipe, you can just use public getter

Comment: Okay. Corrected my question. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the Thread under `ExecutorService`, which gives a way to catch return value
 after `Thread` execution.

`ExecutorService#submit((java.lang.Runnable, T))` - Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that task. The Future's get method will return null upon successful completion.

Code snippet:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<String> future1 = executor.submit(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), response.getOutputStream()),String.class);
Future<String> future2 = executor.submit(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), response.getOutputStream()),String.class);

future1.get();// will block the execution for you and the Thread completion
future2.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold a reference to SyncPipe and use public getter:

```
SyncPipe pipe = new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream())
Thread thread = new Thread(pipe);
thread.start();
thread.join();
pipe.getStr();

....

class SyncPipe implements Runnable{
    String str="";
    public String getStr(){
        return str;
    }
....
```

Comment: Hey it's printing null value for str, updated my code./ Pl check.

Comment: And this prints something: ```System.out.println(str);```?

Comment: Yes. that's printing as expected to.

Comment: And are you sure you're calling ```join()``` on the Thread before you call the getter? I've just tried that and it works as expected.

Comment: When I used join, no output at all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with getting value from thread like this. The problem must be somewhere else. Are you absolutely sure that this ```str = str + IOUtils.toString(istrm_, "UTF-8");``` actually reads something?

Comment: Yes, because I was getting output when I used System.out.println(str);